# What's the meaning of sub-voxel in computer graphics？

Tags: 3d-reconstruction

I read an image-based 3D-reconstruction paper, and there is a paragraph as following:

Volumetric representations, which have been extensively adopted in early deep leaning-based 3D reconstruction techniques, allow the parametrization
of 3D shapes using regular voxel grids. As such, 2D
convolutions used in image analysis can be easily
extended to 3D. They are, however, very expensive
in terms of memory requirements, and only a few
techniques can achieve ***sub-voxel*** accuracy.

So what's the meaning of sub-voxel?

Comment: This question may be a better fit for https://dsp.stackexchange.com/